# Process 'command '28.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 after changing android package

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I changed the android package by this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/10810233),

and now I get an error

> Process 'command 'D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

How i can fix this?

1. Build -> Clean project
2. Build -> Rebuild project

   is not working

Answer (score 1):

1.Make sure your aidl file is in package like:

```
com.xxx.xxx.xxx.aidl
```

2.If your aidl file contains List, please use it like this:

```
void setResouces(in List<String> paths);
```